# The scrapy-redis program does not close automatically

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, web-crawler

- Scrapy-redis framework, redis stored xxx: requests have been crawled finished, but the program is still running, how to automatically stop the program, rather than has been running?
- The running code:

`2017-08-07 09:17:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-07 09:18:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`

- I use scrapy-redis to crawl a site, scrapy-redis will not automatically shut down, still have to ask url, but has no url. So it will always`scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`

Comment: What do your question even mean?

Comment: Wolcome to Stack Overflow. We can not help you if you state questions like this.

Comment: I use scrapy-redis to crawl a site, scrapy-redis will not automatically shut down, still have to ask url, but has no url. So it will always```scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrapy-redis` will always wait for new urls to be pushed in the redis queue. When the queue is empty, the spider goes in **idle** state and waits new urls. That's what I used to close my spider once the queue is empty.

When the spider is in **idle** (when it does nothing), I check if there is still something left in the redis queue. If not, I close the spider with `close_spider`. The following code is located in the `spider` class:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    from_crawler = super(SerpSpider, cls).from_crawler
    spider = from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
    return spider


def idle(self):
    if self.q.llen(self.redis_key) <= 0:
        self.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='finished')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `scrapy-redis` is made to be always open waiting for more urls to be pushed in the redis queue, but if you want to close it you could do it with a pipeline, here:

```
class TestPipeline(object):

def __init__(self, crawler):
    self.crawler = crawler
    self.redis_db = None
    self.redis_len = 0

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler)

def open_spider(self, spider):        
    self.redis_len = len(spider.server.keys('your_redis_key'))

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.redis_len -= 1
    if self.redis_len <= 0:
        self.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'No more items in redis queue')

    return item
```

I will explain how it works in `open_spider` the pipeline get the total of keys in the redis queue and in `process_item` it decrements the `redis_len` variable and when it reach zero send a close signal in the last item.

Comment: Useful.I will try it.
Thk!