# SCHEDULER_IDLE_BEFORE_CLOSE does not work in scrapy-redis

Tags: scrapy

I set the `SCHEDULER_IDLE_BEFORE_CLOSE = 10`, but spiders were not closed and kept in state of IDLE.

I overrided the spider_idle function of scrapy-redis in class RedisMixin:

```
def spider_idle(self):
    self.schedule_next_requests()
    # raise DontCloseSpider
```

Now the spiders would close but couldnot consumed all start_urls completely!

DO I need to check the start_urls and requests in redis by myself, to determined whether raise DontCloseSpider or not?

I add idle function in my spider (refer to [The scrapy-redis program does not close automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540569/the-scrapy-redis-program-does-not-close-automatically))

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    from_crawler = super(SkuSpider, cls).from_crawler
    spider = from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.my_idle, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
    return spider

def my_idle(self):
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=REDIS_DB)
    if (r.llen(REDIS_START_URLS_KEY % {'name': self.name}) == 0 
        and r.zcard('%s:requests' % self.name) == 0):
        self.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='finished')
```

Very thanks for your help!